# Fastest apply function on groups for 2D numpy array

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Let's say I have a 2D matrix of data and I want to apply a function to groups within that matrix.

For example:

[image: Data] .  .  .  . [image: Index]

For every unique index, I want to apply some function `f`.

E.g. for the group with `index = 1` the function `f` is applied to the values `0.556, 0.492, 0.148` (see first column) and for group `index = 2` the function is applied to value `0.043`.

Additionally:

1. The function must broadcasts the result to the original size of the input data.
2. The groups are unique per column. You can see this in the example above where every group only contains values that are in the same column.

Then what is the absolute quickest way to perform this operation in Python?

I'm currently doing the following (with random data [2000x500] and 5 random groups per column):

```
import numpy as np

rows = 2000
cols = 500
ngroup = 5

data = np.random.rand(rows,cols)
groups = np.random.randint(ngroup, size=(rows,cols)) + 10*np.tile(np.arange(cols),(rows,1))

result = np.zeros(data.shape)                       # Pre-allocating the result
f = lambda x: (x-np.average(x))/np.std(x)           # The function I want to apply
for group in np.unique(groups):                     # Loop over every unique group
    location = np.where(groups == group)            # Find the location of the data
    group_data = data[location[0],location[1]]      # Get the data
    result[location[0],location[1]] = f(group_data) # Apply the function
```

With my hardware, this calculation takes about 10 seconds to complete. Is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: The fastest way will likely depend on the specific `f`. May we assume the one in your snippet will be the one you need?

Comment: @jdehesa Yes, to make this question answerable let’s assume the `f` is as specified in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if the fastest possible one, but this vectorized solution is a lot faster:

```
import numpy as np
import time

np.random.seed(0)
rows = 2000
cols = 500
ngroup = 5

data = np.random.rand(rows,cols)
groups = np.random.randint(ngroup, size=(rows,cols)) + 10*np.tile(np.arange(cols),(rows,1))

t = time.perf_counter()
# Flatten the data
dataf = data.ravel()
groupsf = groups.ravel()
# Sort by group
idx_sort = groupsf.argsort()
datafs = dataf[idx_sort]
groupsfs = groupsf[idx_sort]
# Find group bounds
idx = np.nonzero(groupsfs[1:] > groupsfs[:-1])[0]
idx = np.concatenate([[0], idx + 1, [len(datafs)]])
# Sum by groups
a = np.add.reduceat(datafs, idx[:-1])
# Count group elements
c = np.diff(idx)
# Compute group means
m = a / c
# Repeat means and counts to match data shape
means = np.repeat(m, c)
counts = np.repeat(c, c)
# Compute variance and std
v = np.add.reduceat(np.square(datafs - means), idx[:-1]) / c
s = np.sqrt(v)
# Repeat stds
stds = np.repeat(s, c)
# Compute result values
resultfs = (datafs - means) / stds
# Undo sorting
idx_unsort = np.empty_like(idx_sort)
idx_unsort[idx_sort] = np.arange(len(idx_sort))
resultf = resultfs[idx_unsort]
# Reshape back
result = np.reshape(resultf, data.shape)
print(time.perf_counter() - t)
# 0.09932469999999999

# Previous method to check result
t = time.perf_counter()
result_orig= np.zeros(data.shape)
f = lambda x: (x-np.average(x))/np.std(x)
for group in np.unique(groups):
    location = np.where(groups == group)
    group_data = data[location[0],location[1]]
    result_orig[location[0],location[1]] = f(group_data)
print(time.perf_counter() - t)
# 6.0592527

print(np.allclose(result, result_orig))
# True
```

EDIT: To compute the medians, you can do something as follows:

```
# Flatten the data
dataf = data.ravel()
groupsf = groups.ravel()
# Sort by group and value
idx_sort = np.lexsort((dataf, groupsf))
datafs = dataf[idx_sort]
groupsfs = groupsf[idx_sort]
# Find group bounds
idx = np.nonzero(groupsfs[1:] > groupsfs[:-1])[0]
idx = np.concatenate([[0], idx + 1, [len(datafs)]])
# Count group elements
c = np.diff(idx)
# Meadian index
idx_median1 = c // 2
idx_median2 = idx_median1 + (c % 2) - 1
idx_median1 += idx[:-1]
idx_median2 += idx[:-1]
# Get medians
meds = 0.5 * (datafs[idx_median1] + datafs[idx_median2])
```

The trick here is to use [`np.lexsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) instead of just [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to sort both by group and value. `meds` will be an array with the median of each group, you can then use `np.repeat` on it, as with the means, or whatever else you want with it.

Comment: Epic answer! Learning a lot just from trying to understand your solution. Thank you very much for the time and effort!

Comment: Do you happen to know how to do a `np.median.reduceat` ? So find the median of the groups in a vectorized way?

Comment: @Jean-Paul I have added a way to compute the medians, not with `reduceat` but also in a vectorized way.

Comment: Really nice, I didn't expect the median calculation to be so concise- thanks a lot!